# Prevent columnbreak in a custom environment

Tags: multicol, automation

My document is organized in two (or more) columns and the document consists of chunks of text inside a custom environment. Each of those chunks is not very big and several of them can easily fit within a single column. I prefer to treat this custom environment as an indivisible block. However every so often, they flow over to the next column (or page). I usually force a columnbreak before that chunk using `\vfill\null\columnbreak` and everything is fine.

I would like to know if it possible to do this automatically. Can I redefine my custom environment with some command so that it flows over to the next column (or page) intact without breaking.

Lets say my environment is called `intact`. In the MWE, the third `intact` chunk gets broken. I can prevent it temporarily ... but only till the previous chunks are not modified.

Can I instead change the definition of `intact` itself so this is taken care of?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{intact}[1]{
    \textbf{\underline{#1}}
}{
    \hrule
}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{You talkin to me? You talkin to me? Well I'm the only one here. Who the hell you talkin to? You talkin to me? You talkin to me? Well I'm the only one here. Who the hell you talkin to?}

\begin{document}
    Let there be light ...
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{intact}{First}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
        \begin{intact}{Second}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
        %\vfill\null\columnbreak % uncommenting this line resolves the problem temporarily i.e, till any of the above "intact"s is not modified.
        \begin{intact}{Third}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
        \begin{intact}{Fourth}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
        \begin{intact}{Fifth}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about putting it into a `minipage`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newlength{\oldindent}
\setlength{\oldindent}{\parindent}

\newenvironment{intact}[1]{%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
    \setlength{\parindent}{\oldindent}\textbf{\underline{#1}}
}{%
    \vspace{5pt}\hrule\vspace{4pt}
    \end{minipage}
}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{You talkin to me? You talkin to me? Well I'm the only one here. Who the hell you talkin to? You talkin to me? You talkin to me? Well I'm the only one here. Who the hell you talkin to?}

\begin{document}
    Let there be light ...
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{intact}{First}
            \sampletext
        \end{intact}
        \begin{intact}{Second}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
        %\vfill\null\columnbreak % uncommenting this line resolves the problem temporarily i.e, till any of the above "intact"s is not modified.
        \begin{intact}{Third}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
        \begin{intact}{Fourth}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
        \begin{intact}{Fifth}
            \sampletext 
        \end{intact}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On can help multicol by using a bottom aligned minipage (i.e., `[b]`) otherwise each bock has a large depth which is not what you want at the bottom of a column. Up-to-date versions of multicol can handle that correctly, but they have to work harder to do so. Also important: there is no indentation in your result, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: I experimented with ``minipage`` and it seems to work fine except one minor glitch. There are unintentional linebreaks in my real document. I have tried to correct that by specifying ``1.01\linewidth`` and it seems to work well. However I am not sure when it will break again.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach indentation was not important however forcing ``\noindent`` may have some unintended consequences though I am not an expert to correctly guess them.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Please look at my renewed answer and tell me if it's better now (I'm not enough expert to completely understand your comment).

Comment: @CarLaTeX yes, exactly my two points. Without the bottom option the minipage has a roughly the same depth as its height, but you don't want to have the material sticking out at the bottom. In earlier versions of multicol that was what was happening more or less. Now multicol notices that something very deep is at the bottom of a column and tries to fix the problem but it means extra work and also the stuff is then sticking out up to \maxdepth which is 5pt typically so not aligning properly.